# What does Python's getstate() actually mean

Tags: python

Python's `getState()` method returns an an object with the current state of the random number generator. However what do the actual numbers in the `getState()` actually represent? For example, when I do `print(getState())` I get `(3, (2147483648L, 766982754L, 497961170L, 3952298588L, ... 2902720905L, 624L), None)` in which the `...` is a very long list of numbers. What do the numbers, more specifically the numbers containing L in this object actually represent?

Answer (score 1):

Python's `random` module uses a [Mersenne twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) to compute random numbers. The state is a three-tuple.

The first element (`3` in your case) is a version number.

The next element is a list of of 625 numbers, of which the first 624 are basically a list of pre-computed random numbers. The last item seems to be 624 in all cases. You can read about the meaning of these numbers in the linked Wikipedia article.

The last element is called `gauss_next` in the source code of the random module. It is used to generate random numbers from a Gaussian distribution, more specifically it is the coefficient for the standard deviation: `mu + gauss_next*sigma` where `mu` is the mean and `sigma` the standard deviation.

Comment: By following the Wikipedia article, the 1st state variable should be 0 (and the next should be 1) if the seed 0 is used, however, seeding from 0 and passing version=1 don't make the 1st state variable 0. Why? Try it out: https://www.online-python.com/Pxp4KycsCj

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a duplicate of [internal state of python random module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289462/internal-state-of-python-random-module)

You may investigate Mersenne Twister if interested.

By the way I guess you are using Python2 because there is no long int in Python3 (numbers such as 2147483648L ending with `L`)